# Integrating over or under this object....

Tags: calculus, integration

There is clearly a kink in my understanding of double integrals with polar coordinates.

Our problem is to find the volume enclosed by the hyperboloid $-x^2-y^2+z^2=1$ and plane $z=2$.  I correctly figure the bounds to be $D = \{ (r,\theta) | 0 \leq \theta \leq 2\pi,0 \leq r \leq \sqrt{3} \} .$

But I have trouble finding if we are integrating between the section of the hyperboloid and the disk $r=1$ at $z=0$ or $z=2$.

While $r\sqrt{1-r^2}drd\theta$ would make some sense as an integrand, I essentially dont know if I am integrating (ie, finding volume) *under* or *over* the surface of the hyperboloid.  Thanks!

Comment: Should it be $-x^2 -y^2 +z^2 =1$?

Comment: Fixed.  Sorry about that one....

Comment: Your set $D$ is the region over which you are integrating. If you wish to find the surface area you'll have to evaluate $\iint dS$. I remember trying this once. The integral was intractable.

Comment: To reword the question: How do I tell the difference between finding the area bound by the hyperboloid and the plane z=2 and the hyperboloid and the area plane z = 0 (I suppose the other bound would be the cylynder enclosing the intersection of the hyperboloid and the plane z=2 in this case .... :/

Comment: The area bounded by the hyperboloid and the plane $z=2$ seems to me to be simply the area of the hyperboloid when $1 \leq z \leq 2$. I do not understand what surface you mean between the hyperboloid and the plane $z=0$.

Comment: [Facepalm](http://i.imgur.com/L3J6n.jpg).  Did I say surface?  I meant volume......

Comment: You should edit your question to reflect that then, haha. All the way I was assuming you were performing surface integration.

Comment: [Again.](http://i.imgur.com/L3J6n.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Since you've said in the comments that you wish to find the volume, this can be done using a triple integral. The region in the $xy$ plane can be written in polar coordinates as the set $D$ you have said. As for the $z$ limits, we'll have $\sqrt{1+x^2+y^2} \leq z \leq 2$, therefore

$$V = \iiint dV = \int_0^{\sqrt{3}} \int_0^{2 \pi} \int_{\sqrt{1+r^2}}^2 r \, dz \, d \theta \, dr.$$

This ensures that you are computing the volume between the hyperboloid and the plane $z=2$.

In general when you compute volumes you compute from the $xy$ plane up to whatever height you wish. When we set $\sqrt{1+x^2+y^2} \leq z \leq 2$ we are essentially doing two computations: the volume of the cylinder of height $2$ and subtracting the volume up to the hyperboloid, giving the volume desired.